# Liferay 7.3 war deployment takes to long for development

Tags: java, maven, module, liferay, tomcat9

I'm trying to setup a development ambient using Liferay (7.3) DevStudio in Eclipse, where I have a liferay module which was/is a Maven webapp project ( deployed in the past to IBM Websphere Portal ). Everything works well, I can open liferay portal and access my webapp application.

The problem I have is that this app is more or less 80mb with a tone of files already and every time I do a change in java files or any other files, after compilation of the project ( which is fast btw ) it begins the process of deployment do the internal tomcat of liferay bundle.

On deployment it is created a war file package (based on maven packaging option[war]) and copied by liferay to the deploy folder of the internal tomcat and this takes to long...

My objective is to alter anything from project structure ( liferay or module ), pom.xml to allow me to run the project while on development, every time I do a change I don´t want to deploy the war in this fashion. I want only to tomcat assume the changed filed and not the complete app...

What am I missing here? Can I do some hot deploy or something in tomcat? I mean develop with the exploded project inside tomcat?

I hope you understand and feel free to ask for any detail you need to formulate an answer...

So sorry for the long text... Here is the project structure, pom.xml and system.out log

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>something.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <finalName>MyProject</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding> 
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                    <warName>MyProject</warName>                
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/version/build-version.properties</file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>  
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.portal.kernel</artifactId>
            <version>9.8.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.util.bridges</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.util.taglib</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        ...other project dependencies not relevant
    </dependencies>
    
</project>
```

This is the look of project structure in Eclipse:
[image: Liferay project structure]

Console log starting ok building war

[image: Starting log]

This is where it takes to long...deploying the war file. I don´t want to deploy the war file I want to develop with the project exploded in tomcat so that when I change a few files I only want these changes to be assumed.

[image]

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/data/errors/text when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/13447)

Answer (score 1):

You're deploying an 80MB artifact - I assume that it largely is 80MB because of the dependencies that you labelled as "irrelevant" in the pom.xml above.

These dependencies - even if unchanged - need to be analyzed (which means: unpacked, parsed, processed) upon deployment. Liferay transforms a WAR file into an OSGi bundle - and if you want to accellerate that process, you can do the same, before the actual deployment: The easiest way, with the most control on your end, would be if you transform your plugin into an OSGi bundle yourself.

In case your dependencies are already OSGi bundles, you deploy them once, and any update to your own component will be an update to a tiny component (now that the dependencies are out of it). Otherwise, OGSi'ify them, and you'll save yourself from redeployment.

You can also split your single monolithic plugin into multiple smaller bundles, cutting down even further and easing maintainability and improving architectural independence of various parts of your own plugin.

Comment: Hello Olaf, actually the 80mb are mainly project files and not dependencies files. But you are right its a big monolithic plugin indeed...and there are 22mb of dependencies wich makes the build time more or less 1 min. I'll continue my search based on your answear thx...